# The function is executed as many times as it wants jquery js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When we click OPEN, without adding to FAV first
then OPEN works fine, heals when we add a line of code
html to FAV then OPEN executes as many positions as possible
e.g. OPEN 3 from below, performed 3 times.

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box-right">
            <ul class="list_links" id="list_links_fav"></ul>
            <ul class="list_links" id="list_links">
              <li class="list-group-item"> <button id="open" value="pathWay_value1">open</button> <span>pathWay_value1</span> <button id="fav"> add to fav</button> </li>
              <li class="list-group-item"> <button id="open" value="pathWay_value2">open</button> <span>pathWay_value2</span> <button id="fav"> add to fav</button> </li>
              <li class="list-group-item"> <button id="open" value="pathWay_value3">open</button> <span>pathWay_value3</span> <button id="fav"> add to fav</button> </li>
              <li class="list-group-item"> <button id="open" value="pathWay_value4">open</button> <span>pathWay_value4</span> <button id="fav"> add to fav</button> </li>
              <li class="list-group-item"> <button id="open" value="pathWay_value5">open</button> <span>pathWay_value5</span> <button id="fav"> add to fav</button> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button#fav').on('click', function () {
          console.log('Clicked #fav');
          fav_value = $(this).closest("li").html();
          console.log(fav_value);
          $('#list_links_fav').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + fav_value + '</li>');
          $(this).closest("li").remove();
          console.log("Added to fav");

              $(document).ready(function(){
              $('button#open').on('click', function () {
              console.log('Clicked #open');
              var fired_button = $(this).val();
              console.log(fired_button);
              });
              });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button#open').on('click', function () {
          console.log('Clicked #open');
          var fired_button = $(this).val();
          console.log(fired_button);
  });
});
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: You are making new click event bindings every time the click of the fav button happens.  That is potentially creating duplicate bindings.  General practice recommends not creating bindings within other bindings

Comment: Also web standards expressly states that ids should not be repeated.

Comment: You're using the same id="open" and "fav" multiple times. ids have to be unique, better change this to a class, otherwise your HTML is not valid.

Comment: @matthias_h ok, but it's still not my solution, maybe some other suggestions?

Comment: I've added the adjusted code in this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ws4rkoqc/ (changing ids to classes and removing the doubled click event handler for the open button) and I think it's working as expected, or is there any issue?

Comment: I've adjusted the code so the click events are also working for the elements that are added when clicking "Fav" in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ws4rkoqc/1/

Comment: @matthias_h ugh, it works! now I understand, many thanks to you!

Comment: Glad that I was able to help :)